# how to add images to the expandable list view for the parent?

Tags: android, image, expandablelistview

How can I use imageheader in expandable list view??

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what do you consider as imageheader?

Comment: parent ViewGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what is imagehader but to set image in expandablelistview header you should do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    }


    ImageView imageheader = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageheader);
    return convertView;
}
```